# vue-cli,localstrageでカウントを再読み込みしても永続化できるようにしたい

Tags: vue.js

環境
windows10(64)
"vue": "^2.6.10",
"vuetify": "^2.1.0",
"vue-cli":"3.11.0",
"node":"v11.13.0",
プログラミング歴　４か月ほど

## 作っているもの

講義さぼり回数をカウントするtodoリストを作っています。

https://vuejs-http-e3587.firebaseapp.com/

## やりたいこと

ページロード（再読み込み）してもカウントが永続化できるようにしたい。

## 実際の動作（画像）

ロードするとカウントが0に戻ってしまう。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

↓再読み込み
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
↓するとカウントが0に戻ってしまう。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

問題が発生しているコード
https://github.com/masal9pse/courageTodo/blob/develop/src/components/Count.vue

## 試したこと

その１　単純にカウントにlocalstrageを使う

```
@@ -37,6 +37,7 @@ export default {
  },
  mounted() {
    this.todos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todos")) || [];
    this.count = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("count")) || [];
  },
  methods: {
    addTodo() {
@@ -48,7 +49,9 @@ export default {
      }
      let setJson = JSON.stringify(this.todos);
      let setCount = JSON.stringify(this.count);
      localStorage.setItem("todos", setJson);
      localStorage.setItem("count", setCount);
      this.name = "";
    },
    increment(todo) {
```

Count.vueのコードhttps://github.com/masal9pse/courageTodo/blob/develop2/src/components/Count.vue

## 結果

上記と同じでロードすると0になる。
コンソールのエラー文はなし。ローカルストレージの保存状況は下記
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

拙い質問ですが、回答お願いします！

Answer (score 1, accepted):

increment, decrementのメソッドでローカルストレージを更新していないためです。

例えば、カウンタを上げたあとにtodoを追加してみてください。その後リロードすれば、追加した直前のカウントは保持されていますよね？

（当該コードは質問内に貼るようにしてください）